# Python Pandas sum unique groupby and total all at the bottom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group a dataframe and sum each group and then sum the entire dataframe at the bottom. I have this working but I'm stumped with the grand total. I would also like to figure out how to have only one value in the host_count for each group.

```
import pandas as pd
# import numpy as np

data = {'host': ['1.1.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '172.16.1.2', '192.168.1.1', '172.16.1.2', '10.2.3.4', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.1'],
        'url': ['capps.test.com', 'attilab-admin.test.com', 'emea-solutions-admin.test.com', 'ilab-admin.test.com', 'learning.test.com', 'mktextfw.test.com', 'sandbox.learning.test.com', 'mynetwork.test.com', 'www.letsdoit.com', 'www.mysite.com']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['host_count'] = df.groupby('host')['url'].transform('count')
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['host', 'url'], columns=None, fill_value=0, dropna=True).sort_values(by='host_count', ascending=False)
print(pivot1)
```

[image: eww image of code]

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc` to add a new row, which goes to the bottom of the frame by default. I think your problem can better be solved with `groupby` rather than `pivot`:

```py
def summarize(group):
    tmp = group.groupby("url").sum()
    tmp.loc["All"] = tmp.sum()
    return tmp

result = df.groupby("host").apply(summarize)
result.loc[("All", "All"), :] = result[result.index.get_level_values("url") != "All"].sum()
```

Comment: That works for the sum of all. Any way to sum each group and then the all?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df.pivot_table(index='host', values='url', aggfunc='nunique', margins=True)
```

Output:

```
             url
host
1.1.1.1        1
10.0.0.1       2
10.2.3.4       1
172.16.1.2     2
192.168.1.1    4
All           10
```

Comment: That is really close. I 'm looking at adding a column with the urls that the ip is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for output like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is getting close, but I would like to sum each group based on the "host" "url" group and then sum the total count.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'host': ['1.1.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '172.16.1.2', '192.168.1.1', '172.16.1.2', '10.2.3.4', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.1'],
       'url': ['capps.test.com', 'attilab-admin.test.com', 'emea-solutions-admin.test.com', 'ilab-admin.test.com', 'learning.test.com', 'mktextfw.test.com', 'sandbox.learning.test.com', 'mynetwork.test.com', 'www.letsdoit.com', 'www.mysite.com']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['host_count'] = df.groupby('host')['url'].transform('count')
pivot1 = df.pivot_table(index=['host', 'url'], values='host_count', aggfunc='nunique')
pivot1.loc[("All", "All"), :] = pivot1.sum()

print(pivot1)
```

Comment: This section is for answers. If you want to add your attempted code or other supporting/clarifying information for your original question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73838360/edit) the original post and insert it there instead.